# Difference between date now() and date inside table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

Here my query :

```
$sql = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF AS diff( DAY, (SELECT date_expire FROM tbl_rec), now())";

$query = mysql_qery($sql);
```

I need a return that will be an array in php while.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TIMEDIFF` to get the difference between 2 times

```
$query = "select timediff(date_expire, now()) diff 
          from tbl_rec;";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
echo $row['diff'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query for **date difference**.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),date_add) as diff FROM `Table_name`;
```

i.e, to get date difference only. So for your table see the query below

```
$sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),date_expire) as diff FROM `tbl_rec`;
$query = mysql_query($sql,$connection);
```

To see the output, first run the sql query in your mysql admin or in command prompt.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),date_expire) as diff FROM `tbl_rec`;
```

Answer (score -1):

The query is just:

```
$sql = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF AS diff( DAY, (SELECT date_expire FROM tbl_rec), now())";
```

and you can generate the array like so (assuming you are using MySQL):

```
$time= array();

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    $time= $row['diff'];
}
```

Comment: why down vote also mention the reason in comment to down voting?